# Copy State of Groups of Checkboxes based on another Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form that has repeating demographic info in 5 separate sections. I want to copy all the demographic info from one section to another if the user clicks yes on a radio and then selects the appropriate section to copy the info from.

I've got this working with text inputs without issue however it fails completely with check boxes. I managed to create a working demo of what I'd like in jsfiddle however the checkbox portion does not work on my form so I was wondering if anyone had any other suggestions.

The demographic info sections mirror each other 100% but it is possible someone would want to put different demographic info in different sections, hence why we're not just duplicating or cloning the input.

```
<div id="toolSet1">
<h3>
Tool Set 1 (complete all fields then select 'Yes' radio)
</h3>
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="race1" id="race1">Check this box!
  <br>
  <input type="textarea" class="textBlock1" name="textBlock1" id="textBlock1">
</div>
<br>
<br> 
Will the demographic information for this tool set be identical to another tool set you have already completed?
<input type="radio" name="demoInfoSame" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="demoInfoSame" value="no">No
<br>
<br>
<div class="hidden" name="toolList" id="toolList">
  From which tool set would you like to copy demographic information?
  <ul class="toolSetList">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet" id="patStudyEstimate" disabled>Patient Study Estimate (check this one)</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet" disabled>Patient Registry</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet" disabled>Electronic Data Capture</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet" disabled>Data Extraction</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet" disabled>Patient Recruitment</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="toolSet2">
<h3>
Tool Set 2
</h3>
  Name2:
  <input type="text" class="name2" name="name2">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" class="race2" name="race2" id="race2">
  <br>
  <input type="textarea" class="textBlock2" name="textBlock2" id="textBlock2">
</div>
<br>
<div class="hidden" name="finalStep" id="finalStep">
<h2>
Now click 'No' radio button.
</h2>
</div>

//Reveal Section and Enable Inputs/Hide Section, Clear Fields, Disable Inputs
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio][name=demoInfoSame]').change(function() {
    if (this.value == 'yes') {

      $('#toolList').fadeIn('slow').find('input').prop('disabled', false);

    } else if (this.value == 'no') {

      $('#finalStep').fadeOut('slow')
      $('#toolList').fadeOut('slow').find('input').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#toolList').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false).end();
      $('#toolSet2').find('input.name2').val('').end();
      $('#toolSet2').find('input.textBlock2').val('').end();
      $('#toolSet2').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',false).end();
    }
  });
});

//Autofill Form Based on Checkbox State
var myInput = $('#name1');
var copyTextArea = $('#textBlock1');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#patStudyEstimate').change(function() {
    if (this.checked)
      $('#toolSet2').find('input.name2').val(myInput.val());
      $('#toolSet2').find('input.textBlock2').val(copyTextArea.val());
      $('#finalStep').fadeIn('slow');
      $( '#toolSet2' ).children( 'input:checkbox' ).each( function( i ) {
            var toolSet1Checks = $('#toolSet1' ).children( 'input:checkbox' ).eq( i                 ).prop( 'checked' );
                if ( toolSet1Checks )
            {
            $( this ).prop( 'checked', true );
            }
                else
            {
            $( this ).removeProp( 'checked' );
            }
        });
  });
});
```

Working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nephandys/2rh5v8fj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The most important thing I think you should know, is that we can't
>    trigger/handle events from the elements appended to the
>    **DOM**/**body**
>
> So Instead of using this:
>
> ```
> $('input[type=radio][name=demoInfoSame]')
> ```
>
> We'll use this:
>
> ```
> $(document).on("change","input[type='radio'][name*='demoInfoSame']",function(){});
> ```
>
> to Handle clicks coming from any *Yes*/*No* radio button

Here I come to you with a new solution that create iteratively your demographic sections, using `input`, `checkbox` & `radio button`:

```js
var counter=2;
    $(function(){
     

            $(document).on("change","input[type='radio'][name*='demoInfoSame']",function() {

                if (this.value == 'yes') {


                    $(this).find('~ div[id*="toolList"]:first').fadeIn('slow').find('input').prop('disabled', false);

                } else if (this.value == 'no') {
                    $(this).find('~ div[id*="toolList"]:first').fadeOut('slow').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
                    $(this).find('~ div[id*="toolList"]:first').find('input').prop('checked',false).end();
                }
            });





       $(document).on("click",".toolSetList input[type='checkbox']",function () {
            if(this.checked) {
                /*************** First Part 'ToolSet' Div ***************/
                    //Here we Copy the content of the first toolSet div to the new toolSet div
                var idDiv1='toolSet'+counter;
                $("body").append("<div id="+idDiv1+"></div>");
                var prevDiv='#toolSet'+(counter-1);
                $('#'+idDiv1).append($(prevDiv).html());
                $('#'+idDiv1+" h3").text($(this).parent().text());

                //Now we Handle the id's name & content of the elements of the first toolSet
                $('#'+idDiv1+" input[id*='name']").attr('id',('name'+counter));
                $('#'+idDiv1+" input[id*='name']").attr('name',('name'+counter));
                $('#'+idDiv1+" input[id*='name']").val($(prevDiv+" input[id*='name']").val());
                $('#'+idDiv1+" input[id*='race']").attr('id',('race'+counter));
                $('#'+idDiv1+" input[id*='race']").attr('name',('race'+counter));
                $('#'+idDiv1+" input[id*='textBlock']").attr('id',('textBlock'+counter));
                $('#'+idDiv1+" input[id*='textBlock']").attr('name',('textBlock'+counter));
                $('#'+idDiv1+" input[id*='textBlock']").val($(prevDiv+" input[id*='textBlock']").val());
                /************************** # ***************************/

                /*************** Second Part 'Text' & 'Inputs' between the Divs ***************/
                    $("body").append("<br>\n" +
                        "<br> Will the demographic information for this tool set be identical to another tool set you have already completed?\n" +
                        "<input type=\"radio\" name="+("demoInfoSame"+counter)+"  value=\"yes\">Yes\n" +
                        "<input type=\"radio\" name="+("demoInfoSame"+counter)+" value=\"no\">No\n" +
                        "<br>\n" +
                        "<br>");
                /************************************ # *************************************/

                /*************** Third & Final Part The group of "Checkbox"  ***************/
                var idDiv2='toolList'+counter;
                $("body").append("<div class=\"hidden\" name="+idDiv2+" id="+idDiv2+"></div><hr>");
                var prevDiv2='#toolList'+(counter-1);
                $('#'+idDiv2).append($(prevDiv2).html());
                /************************************ # *************************************/



                counter++;
            }

        });
    });
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
  }

  .toolSetList {
    list-style: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toolSet1">
  <h3>
    Tool Set 1 (complete all fields then select 'Yes' radio)
  </h3>
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1">
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="race1" id="race1">Check this box!
  <br>
  <input type="textarea" class="textBlock1" name="textBlock1" id="textBlock1">
</div>
<br>
<br>
Will the demographic information for this tool set be identical to another tool set you have already completed?
<input type="radio" name="demoInfoSame" value="yes">Yes
<input type="radio" name="demoInfoSame" value="no">No
<br>
<br>
<div class="hidden" name="toolList1" id="toolList1">
  From which tool set would you like to copy demographic information?
  <ul class="toolSetList">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet"  disabled>Patient Study Estimate (check this one)</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet" disabled>Patient Registry</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet" disabled>Electronic Data Capture</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet" disabled>Data Extraction</li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toolSet" disabled>Patient Recruitment</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr>
```

> The Javascript Code is Commented in such a way you can understand what
>   I did, And I still open for more questions

Best Regards !

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't think I was clear enough. I have a form around 275 fields so it's hard for me to post the code directly. If you see this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nephandys/xwt7p460/ I want to be able to copy the checkbox groups from one tool set to the other by answering the question and clicking the checkbox for the corresponding tool set as seen in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/nephandys/2rh5v8fj/ It's working in that example but then when I import that code to my form it fails to work for checkboxes. Text and textareas I've got. I'd prefer not to clone b/c dif. names/ids.

Comment: @Neph Ok, now at Work I'll try to edit my answer when I'm home. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm going to keep banging my head against it today. Here's a pastebin of the actual form to give you an idea: https://pastebin.com/BprVD5Da

Comment: @Neph Hello I edited my answer, it take me 4 hours of hard to work to achieve it, Hope it will help ! Good Luck

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @Neph Welcome ^^ glad it helps :)